# How to measure RTT using python httplib, Httpserver

Tags: python, sockets, httplib, basehttpserver, basehttprequesthandler

I made an HTTP proxy using the httplib and BaseHTTPServer, Now I want to know if there is way that I can calculate the RTT to each server. I don't want to use ping method because I want to calculate the RTT for each object's server passing through my proxy. 
Can I edit the above library to achieve my target or is there something like this already ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for your connections, and then you can use [Reponse.elapsed](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=elapsed#requests.Response.elapsed) to determine how long it took from the first byte being sent and finishing receiving and parsing the headers.

Comment: Hi I saw this, but for that I will have to change the whole implementation, Is there anyother way ?

Comment: If you're using httplib3 it looks like you can call `get_connect_duration()` from your request, I believe its what the Requests library uses for `elapsed`. If you're not using a version of httplib that supports that functionality, you can look at how to implement it [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/xbmc/scripts/ci/756e952bb5a067c41a792d6a924630637445c1ff/tree/script.module.requests2/lib/requests/packages/urllib3/util.py). Good luck!